# Micropython ESP32 S3 UART pins

Tags: python, esp32, micropython

Hi I am currently connecting a SIM800L to an ESP32 s3 using pins rx: 18, tx: 17

and running this code:

```
from machine import UART
id = 1
gsm = UART(id, 115200)
```

This then returns the error for both id=1 and id=2:

```
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (LoadStoreAlignment). Exception was unhandled.
```

Can't use id =0 as it is reserved for REPL

Here is the pin diagram of the esp32-s3

[image]

Comment: does it work for id=0?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki No that's revered for REPL